# How to redirect sound sink to source

Tags: linux, audio, pulse-audio

I sometimes stream games for my friends on Discord, but Discord for Linux is unable to capture the game sounds. I use Pulseaudio + ALSA combo for my sound needs. I thought of solving this issue by making virtual source device, which would combine the sounds from my microphone and the output of my computer. My best shot looked like those commands:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=loopback
pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo sink=loopback
pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor sink=loopback
```

The idea was that I would be able to slect this device as an input from discord. Sadly there seem to be two problems with my attempt. First the *loopback* doesn't implicitly mix the two audio sources and only binds itself to the last one. Second Discord doesn't recognize *loopback* as input, probably because it is audio sink despite having *loopback.monitor* source.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do, or at least something similar?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/868817/collecting-and-mixing-sound-input-from-different-microphones <- try a variant of this.

Comment: I assume Discord doesn't show the "monitor" virtual sources either? (Because that's literally how you'd do it normally -- capture from the sink's ".monitor" source...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The automatic monitor that is created is not recognized by a lot of programs as a source.  Try remapping the source:

pactl load-module module-remap-source master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor source_name=virt_mic source_properties=device.description=VirtualMic

That should show up in Discords list

Answer (score 0):

You can manually reassign the sink to use in the Recording tab of pavucontrol.

Comment: Does not work if the application set custom sink along with `sink_dont_move`: monitor devices aren't usually listed by applications when selecting input device (eg. Zoom)

Comment: In the case of Zoom you can just pick the device on the app itself.

Comment: Zoom does not show monitor devices, unfortunately.